# tailing Network Logs and console.log in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to tail logs in my content.js file inside the chrome extension.I want to know how to tail network and console.logs

Comment: The question is too vague/broad currently. Please clarify what exactly you want to achieve and how it would work (an example of a typical scenario).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, just right click on extension and say inspect